# What is GetX Controller?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, flutter-state

I am new with getX and I don't understand what is the purpose of GetX Controller. Based on my understanding, It basically hold variables and this is where everything changes inside the state. Can someone explain further

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than holding variables for state change, it provides observability. It allows declaring a variable as observable, which is by using ***.obs*** and the whole class elements can be under control or operatable. To make it work you should initialize it by using Get.put or the LazyPut method.

For more, refer [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V0oxG3tWiwk&t=1648s).